# Jquery passing 2 class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to pass the divs and divs2, so when I click the next button both divs will change.

Can anyone please help me with how to pass multiple classes inside if-else and jQuery?

--code not mine--

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
          $(this).hide();
      });

      $("#next").click(function() {
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
          $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
          $(".divs div:visible").hide();
          $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
      });

      $("#prev").click(function() {
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
          $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
          $(".divs div:visible").hide();
          $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
      });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <div class="cls1">1</div>
  <div class="cls2">2</div>
  <div class="cls3">3</div>
</div>

<a id="prev">prev</a>
<a id="next">next</a>

<div class="divs2">
  <div class="cls1">1</div>
  <div class="cls2">2</div>
  <div class="cls3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `$(".divs div:visible")` to `$(".divs div:visible,.divs2 div:visible")` *or* to `$(".divs,.divs2").find("div:visible")` *or* change to add/remove a "visible" class

Answer (score 0):

**Try using:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
          $(this).hide();
      });
      
      $(".divs2 div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
          $(this).hide();
      });

      $("#next").click(function() {
        if ($(".divs div:visible,.divs2 div:visible").next().length != 0)
          $(".divs div:visible,.divs2 div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
          $(".divs div:visible,.divs2 div:visible").hide();
          $(".divs div:first,.divs2 div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
      });

      $("#prev").click(function() {
        if ($(".divs div:visible,.divs2 div:visible").prev().length != 0)
          $(".divs div:visible,.divs2 div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
          $(".divs div:visible,.divs2 div:visible").hide();
          $(".divs div:last,.divs2 div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
      });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <div class="cls1">1</div>
  <div class="cls2">2</div>
  <div class="cls3">3</div>
</div>

<a id="prev">prev</a>
<a id="next">next</a>

<div class="divs2">
  <div class="cls1">1</div>
  <div class="cls2">2</div>
  <div class="cls3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine!! thank you so much, just a bit of question what is the use of "(e != 0)"

Comment: That `each e!=0 hide` code is the same as `$(".divs div").hide().first().show()` or `($".divs div").not(":first").hide()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
      $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e%3 != 0)
          $(this).hide();
      });

      $("#next").click(function() {
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
          $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
          $(".divs div:visible").hide();
          $(".divs div.cls1").show();
        }
        return false;
      });

      $("#prev").click(function() {
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
          $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
          $(".divs div:visible").hide();
          $(".divs div.cls3").show();
        }
        return false;
      });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>two-class</title>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="divs">
  <div class="cls1">1</div>
  <div class="cls2">2</div>
  <div class="cls3">3</div>
</div>

<a id="prev">prev</a>
<a id="next">next</a>

<div class="divs">
  <div class="cls1">1</div>
  <div class="cls2">2</div>
  <div class="cls3">3</div>
</div>
    
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>    
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

you don't need to use "two different" classes. here I will post a code that changes the class of second div to "divs". but you need to change your script in the third line. instead of using "e != 0" you can use "e%3 != 0". like the code that I will post.

this is working when you have 3 "sub-div" in each "divs" class. if you have 4, use "e%4 != 0" instead.

Comment: Sadly, not working! But thanks for the help tho:)

Comment: What is the meaning of e%3?

Comment: it means the reminder. if you divide 2/3 the reminder is 2. so when you have 3 div in each "divs" class, you can separate them in this way. because $(".divs div") includes all 6 div in your html file.

Comment: you can also read jQuery documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/each/
in that documentation probably "index" have the similar role of "e".